# Error while importing pdftotext module in spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pdftotext, poppler

So, I have been trying to installing pdftotext module I tried a lot of methods, the only one that worked was by using miniconda for installing poppler and then pdftotext (the main problem with anaconda was that poppler was not getting installed). So, after I installed it with miniconda and tried to import it with spyder it gave error, so then I manually copied every file related to pdftotext from miniconda to anaconda (considering their locations). Now if I type pip install pdftotext in anaconda it says that requirement satisfied but then again if I try to import it with spyder, it gives error.[This is the anaconda prompt saying that pdftotext is installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyWFC.png)
[This is the error that shows up after I try to import it in spyder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2clTw.png)

Comment: If you want more peoples help you, make things easyer and simplier.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to properly install packages in Miniconda/Anaconda and make Spyder recognize them.

Answer (score -1):

Run in your In[]:

```
pip.main(["install", "pdftotext"])
```

Your Spider use 3.8.
Please type in terminal ( not  spider) : `python3 -v`